# Is there any syntax to list all rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have this

```
ListObject.ListRows(1).Delete
```

I need something along these lines

```
ListObject.ListRows(All).Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all rows in a ListObject, you can use.

`ListObject.DataBodyRange.Delete`